Why is standing considered "more communal" than kneeling?
I asked catholic.chat this question already, and was unimpressed by the responses.  Apparently the Cdl. Cupich gives for outlawing kneeling while receiving communion is that it is an act of Communal Worship to stand in line and receive communion while still standing, rather than stand in line and receive communion while kneeling (or before a communion rail shoulder to shoulder with your fellow (non-mortal) sinners).
Catholic.chat said:


Posture of Unity: Standing together as a congregation can symbolize a shared commitment and active participation in the worship experience. It visually represents the unity of the faithful as they approach the altar together, highlighting their collective identity as the Body of Christ. Kneeling, while also a posture of reverence, can sometimes create a more individual experience, as it may emphasize personal humility and devotion.

Movement Together: When the faithful stand and process forward to receive Communion, it emphasizes the communal journey of faith. This act of moving together in a line as one body can foster a sense of belonging and shared purpose. Kneeling, on the other hand, might not have the same dynamic of movement and collective action, as individuals may kneel at different times or in different ways.

Joy and Celebration: Standing can convey a sense of joy and celebration, which aligns with the nature of the Eucharist as a feast. This joyful aspect can enhance the communal atmosphere of the liturgy, inviting everyone to share in the experience together. Kneeling, while reverent, might evoke a more solemn or personal tone that could detract from the communal celebration.

Inclusivity: Standing may also be more accessible for all members of the congregation, including those with physical limitations. This inclusivity can enhance the sense of community, ensuring that everyone can participate fully in the reception of Communion.



Everything on this list could be argued that it is enhanced by kneeling while receiving communion.  I know the Church is not a democracy, but it usually draws on the Natural Law for first principles and this is just seems completely backwards.
It also seems like the Cardinal is stressing "Communion" as communion with the congregation over "Communion" as Communion with Christ.  So, I can only assume there has to be a more striking and important reason for which we should overtly ban kneeling to receive Communion which strengthens our Communion with Christ or else this would be a patently evil move on the part of Cardinal Cupich, which I, or any Catholic, would be loathe to accuse him of.
So why is standing considered more communal than kneeling?

I have heard it explained as following the Jewish practice that standing is more respectful than kneeling at least for the posture of praying, see here.  No mention of communality though.  In the meantime, USCCB is said to not want to "regulate posture rigidly in such a way that those who wish to kneel or sit would no longer be free." (see here).

It's merely the Cardinal's personal opinion. As you say, arguments could be given for both postures. Tradition for Western Catholics is that we kneel. Tradition for Eastern Catholics is that they stand. Both postures can be and are appropriate in their respective liturgical contexts. I'm not a fan of trying to impose standing on Western Catholics, since our tradition really is to kneel in the presence of the King. Neither ought we try to impose kneeling on Eastern Catholics, since their litrugical tradition is to stand.

I mean... I know you asked about catholic, but the proper positions for worship in the Orthodox Church are standing, sitting straight, and prostrate on the ground. Bowing is not really one of them, it is rare (I think maybe once or twice a year) where you are expected to bow. So perhaps the logic is the same here? (This is orthodox church talk here)
However... I know that in America the kneeling position is done instead of prostration and pews have knee pads for this purpose. (Honestly made me feel weird the first few times)

Why is standing considered "more communal" than kneeling?
The short answer is that it is not.
This is clearly a new and modern innovative terminology that Cardinal Blasé Cupich has applied to the manner that he desires the Catholic faithful to receive the Eucharist.
In the Extraordinary Form of the the Mass, the faithful knelt down in order to receive Our Lord. That was the traditional manner of receiving communion and the faithful though nothing more than that. One could in a sense say it was the most ”communal” manner of receiving Communion back then. No one ever thought otherwise.
Inventing a new liturgical term like this has no place in the liturgy. It clearly the opinion of Cardinal Cupich and perhaps a few modern liturgists that like bring forth new inventive terms into the liturgy forum. There is no historical bases in which they can impose these trends within liturgy.
”Communal Worship” terminology takes away from essential meanings of the ”Sacrifice of the Mass”! This new terminology is so doctrinally unsound and dangerous for Catholic doctrine.
Unfortunately by employing such a term within the Eucharist Celebration of the Mass, it diminishes what the mass is truly all about. The mass is a sacrifice and not a communal meal. The mass is a renewal of Jesus’ sacrifice on the Cross! Bad liturgical terminology will eventually water down Catholic doctrine and tradition!
It is abhorrent to start employing terms that reduce what the mass, in a truly Catholic manner and understanding.
The “communal” term should be be left outside of liturgical terminology as not only new and modern, but also by the fat that makes the sacrifice of the mass a “ “communal meal”. It sounds more like type of reformation terminology that has no basis in Catholic doctrine, terminology of tradition. It is simply the opinion of Cardinal Cupich.
